# Defining and using project variables in Java CAPS (JCAPS) 5.1.3

Tags: java, frameworks

I'm trying to experiment with project variables in JCAPS, and while I can find some information on how to define them, I cannot find anything on how to actually use them.

Basically, I have a JCD defined that has one item (a filename) that changes between deployments.  I would like to be able to re-use the JCD for multiple deployments, supplying the filename via a project variable (configured in the deployment profile).

Comment: It turns out, as best as I can determine, that project variables cannot be used in the manner that I had hoped.  That is, these variable are not available to a JCD.  Apparently they can only be used in connectivity maps.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to not use the variables.  We have had much better success using property files that we have stored on the server.